# position:absolute позиционируется не абсолютно

Tags: html, css

Имеется элемент с `position:absolute`, он как бы выходит за рамки экрана и не должна показываться та часть, которая выходит за рамки. А у меня получается то, что появляется скролл. Возле него расположен элемент то же с `position:absolute`, но работает он нормально.

```
background:url(../images/men.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
position:absolute;
width:223px;
height:334px;
bottom:0;
right:-190px;
```

Comment: Скролл появляется если выходит за рамки с правой стороны, с левой все нормально. Как такое исправить?

Comment: Так давайте код :). И, кстати, сами координаты top/left указали беглецу?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить в парент контейнер style="overflow: hidden;" ?

Comment: А больше никак? задавать overflow:hidden для всей страницы это нормально?

Comment: Почему нет? Хоть родителю: http://jsfiddle.net/4t9q5/
Хоть бади: http://jsfiddle.net/4t9q5/1/

Comment: Всем спасибо.

Comment: С высотой бади, только аккуратнее надо быть. Погорячился в примере с /1/. Стоит сделать как в бойлерплейте: http://jsfiddle.net/4t9q5/2/